# Get process creation notification in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hook, kernel-extension

I am trying to write kext for Mac OS X which will get notified when any process is started.

In Windows you can do this by calling PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine(...) and specify callback which will be called when the process is starting. This is documented way and it works in all Windows starting from Win 2k.

Is there anything similar for Mac? It seems like this is possible to achieve using kauth process listeners, but process scope has never been implemented in OS X.

Another alternative is to hook SYS_execve and friends, but this is undocumented and unsupported way. I really don't want to go this way.

I don't need any cancelling - just want to be notified when process is started, and get it's pid & path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your question is a bit ambiguous.

Being "notified when any process is started" IMHO means the `fork` syscall, not `execve`. However I have no idea if you can be notified on `fork` by any official API.

If the `execve` is what you are interested in, take a look at the [kernel authorization (kauth) API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2127/_index.html).

You can register in `KAUTH_SCOPE_VNODE` and track for `KAUTH_VNODE_EXECUTE` to be notified before the execve performs (and possibly deny it to succeed by return value from your callback); or register in `KAUTH_SCOPE_FILEOP` and track for `KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC` to be notified after the `execve()` is performed.

Comment: That is an excellent information! I just tried and it works. However, this only works for process start events. How do I get process exit events?

Comment: this way will not work properly. as I told earlier, would better to setup hooks for the task.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this question after 2019:

Apple has a relatively new (macOS 10.15+) `C` framework called [Endpoint Security](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity) which provides process lifecycle events (among other things) and can be consumed either by a user mode daemon or a new "System Extension" (successor to the "Kernel Extension") provided the proper code signing entitlements are secured from Apple. Some notable features are:

- Efficient / Event-driven model ([es_new_client()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/3259700-es_new_client))
- Granular event type subscription model (e.g. `ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_EXEC`, `ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_FORK`, `ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_EXIT` via [es_subscribe()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/3228854-es_subscribe))
- rich event context including `pid`, `uid`, and much more (e.g. An event message for process creation ([es_event_exec_t](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/es_event_exec_t)) includes an [es_process_t](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/es_process_t) field with process details including executable path)
- Events can be 'muted' (masked) based on source (parent) process (e.g. [es_mute_process()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/3228851-es_mute_process)) to help with signal v. noise and performance impact.

Apple has been pushing developers to adopt this new framework for a while now in favor of previous monitoring APIs (like `KAUTH`, `MAC` and `OpenBSM` (`/dev/auditpipe`)) so it's the only solution I can recommend investing in going forward.

There are some WWDC sessions and example projects available on the subject: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/monitoring_system_events_with_endpoint_security

Answer (score 1):

Old question - but - The answer stating SYS_execve hooking is the only way to be notified is incorrect and dangerous. For one, the sysent table is not exported (though arguably it can be found fairly easily). For two, you have to patch the memory and ensure it's rw.

A MUCH better way, in a kext, is to use the MAC framework (that would be Mandatory Access Control). That's in the XNU sources, in the /security branch. The MAC Framework was designed for exactly this kind of operations - i.e. notifications/hooking without actual function or address overwrite, but with callouts. This is also detailed in a book titled "Mac OS X and iOS Internals", Chapter 14.

Answer (score 0):

SYS_execve hooking is only way to be notified when any process is started.
Also, you could try to use DTrace and libdtrace for receiving process started notification; I've been trying that way but without success.

Comment: Hello Александр. Thanks for the reply. I don't think that hooking SYS_execve is a right choice because my kext will be marked by most antiviruses as a rootkit. This approach seems to be quite unstable, as locating sysent table might be tricky. Also, using libdtrace does not seems to be a good idea mostly because the interfaces may change, so I will have to recompile my code. I wonder, can I get notifications about process start/end in user mode application? I wonder, how does most of the antiviruses do the trick in Mac OS? Hooking syscalls?

Comment: You can not get notifications about process start/end in user mode application. Antiviruses are hooking syscalls. If the time lag is not important to you, you could use [this information](http://macosinternals.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7:how-to-obtain-processes-list&catid=3:xnu&Itemid=6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the MAC and KAUTH.

https://www.synack.com/2015/11/17/monitoring-process-creation-via-the-kernel-part-i/