# Subscribe on new process creation from kext and get the pid of this process

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension, mach

I am trying to get the notifications about newly created processes in my kext. According to [Get process creation notification in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249940/get-process-creation-notification-in-mac-os-x) I have subscribed to KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC

But for some strange reason, I have only 2 arguments avaliable - vnode and file name (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html).

The process should be already created at that time and have a pid, but kernel does not give it to me.

Is it possible to get the pid at this time?

Are there other ways to subscribe on new process creation from kext and get the pid of this process?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely get the pid from the file scope: -

```
#include <sys/proc.h>

proc_t self = proc_self();
int pid = proc_pid(self);

// ensure you release the reference to self
proc_rele(self);
```

Comment: this is a pid of process that CREATES a process, not a NEW PROCESS pid

Comment: @GeorgyBuranov, sorry but it works for me. I'm using it in my current project and it returns the pid of the launching process.

Comment: @GeorgyBuranov Note that the `KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC` notification happens after selecting the new executable was successful, but before the process has fully transitioned to the new executable (it is still running as whatever it `fork()`ed from). So if you inspect the `proc_t` object, in some aspects it will definitely still correspond to the old executable, but it will definitely be the new process. See the xnu source for details (grep for KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC and go from there)

Comment: Oddly enough, `current_task()` returns the Mach task for the parent process, while `proc_self()` is the child process's.